# Naive question about particles and spinor fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, spinors

What is the difference between the "real" particle electron (for instance) and the spinor field of electron? I mean, which means that the electron have been described by a spinor field?My question is based upon a phrase from Geroch's book [ http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/geroch-qft-lectures.pdf ]

> Particles with half-integer spin (electrons, neutrinos, etc.) are described by
>   mathematical objects called spinor fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean that particles are the quanta of fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28746/)

Comment: But my question deals specific with Spinor mathematics. Although could be a duplicate.

Comment: The conceptual distinction between quantum fields and their particle-like quanta is the same regardless of spin.