# How to correctly represent a quantum field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

How to correctly represent a quantum field? As something single that fills all space (and particles are excitations of the field just like waves are excitations of a single ocean), or as a set of particles, each of which creates its own field (and when there are no particles, there is no field)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155608, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337423, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48030

Answer (score 1):

In [quantum field theory,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) whether for particle physics or other frames , (for example nuclear physics,) the fields are the plane wave solutions, i.e. without a potential, of the corresponding quantum  equation, filling all points (x,y,z,t), a kind of coordinate system, whether particles exist or not. Creation and annihilation differential  operators create or destroy a particle according to the problem at hand. Feynman diagrams are used as a shorthand describing the interactions.

The field conceptually always exists, for [the standard model of particle physics:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) each particle in the table and their antiparticles is expressed as a field over all space time, electron field,neutrino field etc.

Comment: Every single particle or every type of particle? That is, are all electrons excitations of a single field, or does each individual electron have its own field?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян All electrons and positrons are excitations of a single electron-positron field.

Comment: @G. Smith Does the electron-positron field consist of a large number of individual interacting electrons and positrons? That is, which is more fundamental, a field or a particle? Do particles form a field or does a field create particles?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян We should not have an extended discussion in comments on Anna’s answer.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян  It is mathematics. Your question is the same as asking  : *which is more fundamental, the (x,y,z,t) coordinates or the track of the rocket described* . The field is not described by particles it is the "field"  on which creation and annihilation operators create and annihilate particle states..