# Do fields have meaning in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, coordinate-systems

In classical mechanics the equation of motion of a free particle in polar coordinates is given by
\begin{aligned}
&m\left(\ddot{r}-r \dot{\theta}^{2}\right)=0 \\
&m(r \ddot{\theta}+2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta})=0
\end{aligned}

while in cartesian coordinates is given by
\begin{aligned}
&m\ddot{x}=0 \\
&m\ddot{y}=0.
\end{aligned}

Now suppose we are given the equation
\begin{aligned}
&m\left(\ddot{x}-x \dot{y}^{2}\right)=0 \\
&m(x \ddot{y}+2 \dot{x} \dot{y})=0.
\end{aligned}

If we know  that $x$ represents distances and $y$ represents angle than we know that the last equation represents the motion of a free particle.

Suppose that we have the quantum field Lagrangian
$$\mathscr{L}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{2} m^{2} \phi^{2} \tag 1$$

and suppose we do a field redefinition $\phi=F(\psi)$
such that the Lagrangian $(1)$ turns into

$$\mathscr{L}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{\mu} \psi\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{2} m^{2} \psi^{2} -\frac{g}{4 !} \psi^{4}. \tag 2$$

Now relabeling $\psi \rightarrow \phi$ the Lagrangian we arrive at

$$\mathscr{L}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{\mu} \phi\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{2} m^{2} \phi^{2} -\frac{g}{4 !} \phi^{4}. \tag 3$$

In quantum field theory the **equivalence theorem** says that field redefinitions does not change the theory. So in order for the Lagrangian $(1)$ and $(3)$ represents the same theory the fields $\phi$ in $(1)$ and $(3)$ have to have different meanings.

My question is, do fields have meaning in quantum field theory?

Comment: Fields are not observable quantities.

Comment: @Davide Morgante So how would lagrangian $(1)$ and $(3)$ represents the same theory?

Comment: The name is the same, the use different. see this answer of mine for my opinion https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608775/

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Possible [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69828/equivalence-theorem-of-the-s-matrix)

Comment: Can you give an example of a map that turns ( 1) into (2)?  Note that for the theory to have the same S-matrix, you need $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be mutulally local --- i.e to commute outside the light cone

Comment: The equivalence theorem says redefinitions don't affect the S-matrix, not the QFT.